# Is it possible to write a CGI app that shows its own content (source code) in a textarea?

Tags: html, ruby, textarea, cgi

I use Ruby to write CGI apps, but I think it could be a problem in other languages too. For example this simple approach doesn't work (CGI script name is "self_content"):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require "cgi"

cgi=CGI.new(:accept_charset=>"utf-8")
cgi_header="Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n"


html=<<END
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Self content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Geany 1.26" />
</head>

<body bgcolor=#666>

<form name=f1>
 <textarea name=ta1 cols=90 rows=50>
 #{File.read("self_content")}
 </textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
END

print cgi_header
print html
```

Comment: Yep. Get the current filename from `__FILE__`.

Comment: Yes, to display the content of the actual CGI app in the textarea. I would like to do this with a much bigger app, for demonstartive purposes. To present my works to somebody.